# Private testnet + Smart Contract testing

Tags: private-blockchain, testnets, nodes

is it possible to test a smart contract on a private net with two or more nodes? With nodes I mean two different machines, either virtual or physical, doesn't really matter.

I tried running `geth` with the usual commands however, the two nodes didn't seem to find each other, as `netstat` did not show a connection between the two.

All running on the same local network.

What can I do to debug this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect nodes with the `--bootnodes` command line option of geth, or with the console command `admin.addPeer`. Check the documentation [Connecting to the network](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Connecting-to-the-network).

Comment: Thanks, is `admin.addPeer` on both nodes?

Comment: @fsp It is only needed in one of the nodes.